# Lenguaje c: Impresion de una matriz con subrutinas - Uno de los contadores no se mueve

Tags: c

Quiero imprimir estas matrices con una subrutina, y se imprime la cantidad de veces correcta pero en ambos casos solo se repite la primera fila y no las demas.

imprime asi:

***Matriz Universal***

```
    1       3       4 
    1       3       4 
    1       3       4 
    1       3       4
```

***Matriz Subconjunto***

```
    4       7  
    4       7
```

***Este es mi codigo***

````
#define M 4
#define N 3
#define m 2
#define n 2
int i,j, a, b; 
void impresion(int matriz[a][b], int a, int b); 
int comparacion(int matrizUniversal[M][N], int matrizSubconjunto[m][n]);

int main (){ 
    
    int matrizUniversal[M][N] = {1,3,4, 4,7,8, 2,2,4, 3,5,7}; 
    int matrizSubconjunto[m][n] = {4,7,2,2}; 
    
// Impresion de las matrices 
    printf("\nMatriz Universal\n "); 
        impresion(matrizUniversal, M, N ); 
    
    printf("\nMatriz Subconjunto\n "); 
        impresion(matrizSubconjunto, m, n); 
            
} 

void impresion(int matriz[a][b], int a, int b ){

    for(i=0; i<a; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<b; j++) {
            printf("    %d", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");```
````

Comment: no parece que este correcta la forma de definir la matriz. lo defines como: {1,3,4, 4,7,8, 2,2,4, 3,5,7}, pero si es un array bidimensional, lo suyo seria algo como: {{1,3,4},{ 4,7,8},{2,2,4}, {3,5,7}}.

Comment: hola! realice ese cambio y el problema continua

Answer (score 0):

El problema podrían ser las variables globales *a* y *b* que estás usando como longitud de las dimensiones del array *matriz* en la función *impresion*; éstas están inicializas a cero(0) lo cual produce un array multidimensional de 0x0, además al ser variables y no expresiones constantes el compilador seguramente está interpretando a *matriz* como VLA (array de longitud variable en inglés) en vez de como un array de longitud fija, lo cual podría crear aún más problemas —aunque eso depende del compilador y el optimizador—, no te recomiendo que utilices variables (con o sin **const**) como longitud de arrays locales, mejor usa constantes literales o macros en su lugar, en tal   caso si no conoces la longitud de los arrays en tiempo de compilación (como en este caso) puedes usar punteros para solucionar el problema.

Ejemplo.

```
void impresion(int* matriz, int a, int b)
{
    for(i = 0; i < a; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < b; ++j)
        {
            printf("    %d", *(matriz + (i * b) + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Para llamar a *impresion*, hazlo con casting para que el compilador no genere warnings. Ejemplo: ***impresion((int****)***matrizUniversal, M, N);***